# Expected value of two-variable probability function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to calculate $E(X)$ for X in the probability function

$$ f_{x,y}(j,k)=\frac{1}{36}(j+k) \mbox{ , } j,k=1,2,3.$$

I know that E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y), so I'm thinking that If I calculate E for the entire expression ($\frac{1}{9}((1+1)+(1+2)+...+(3+3))$) and then just divide the result by 2 (as X and Y are identical), I should get E(X).

Doing this, I get the result 4, but the correct number is $\frac{13}{6}$.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the support of the joint variable $(X,Y)$ is the set of ordered pairs of integers from $\{1, 2, 3\}$, so in particular, $X \in \{1, 2, 3\}$.  For this reason, the expectation of $X$ cannot exceed $3$.  That would be like saying the expected value of rolling a fair six-sided die is $10$ when the faces are only numbered from $1$ to $6$.  Do you see why it's absurd?

Second, it is worth noting that the probability function tells you the probability of observing a particular outcome; e.g., $$\Pr[(X,Y) = (1,2)] = \frac{1}{36}(1 + 2) = \frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12},$$ whereas $$\Pr[(X,Y) = (3,3)] = \frac{1}{36}(3 + 3) = \frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6},$$ so the outcome $(1,2)$ is less likely to occur than $(3,3)$.  I don't understand your calculation because you seem to be suggesting that every ordered pair is equiprobable (since you wrote $1/9$).

The correct calculation for the expected value of $X$ is to simply observe that $$\Pr[X = j] = \sum_{k=1}^3 \Pr[(X,Y) = (j,k)] = \sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{1}{36}(j + k) = \frac{3j + 1 + 2 + 3}{36} = \frac{j + 2}{12}, \quad j \in \{1, 2, 3\}.$$  Then $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \sum_{j=1}^3 j \Pr[X = j],$$ which I leave to you to compute.

If you want to do it using your approach, you would write
$$\operatorname{E}[X+Y] = \sum_{j = 1}^3 \sum_{k = 1}^3 (j+k)\Pr[(X,Y) = (j,k)] = \sum_{j = 1}^3 \sum_{k = 1}^3 \frac{(j+k)^2}{36} =  \frac{156}{36} = \frac{13}{3},$$ hence $\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{13}{6}$.

Comment: That cleared everything up! Thank you so so much for the explanation.